# How do I position a notification (tray) icon context menu on Windows XP?

Tags: winapi, notifyicon, trayicon

I'm using C++ and Win32.

I want my context menu and settings dialog to show up near the tray icon. I think I need the icon's coordinates to do that.

Shell_NotifyIconGetRect wasn't available until Windows 7.

WM_CONTEXTMENU is available starting in Win2k, but only provides coordinates in wParam as of Vista (and when specifying NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4).

Comment: Use the position in the mouse messages to place your menu

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I could do that for the settings dialog, too.

Comment: @Erik @Ian What happens if the menu is invoked from the keyboard?

Comment: How do you invoke the context menu with the keyboard?  The icon isn't focusable.

Comment: Not *easily* focusable.  If you invoke the context menu with the keyboard, Windows seems to move the cursor to the center of the icon (at least on Windows 7) so GetMessagePos() would probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving the click coordinates with GetCursorPos works well:

```
// Inside WndProc's switch(message)...
case WM_APP_NOTIFYCALLBACK:
    switch (LOWORD(lParam))
    {
    case WM_CONTEXTMENU: // XP and later
        {
            POINT pt = {};
            if( GetCursorPos(&pt) )
                ShowContextMenu(hWnd, pt, iStatus);
        }
        break;
    // ...
    }
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of solving this is to either use the mouse message coordinates, or [GetMessagePos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for other messages.

Comment: This worked. Part of my question description is wrong. On XP, you DO get WM_CONTEXTMENU callback messages. They just don't have coordinates in wParam, as they do on Vista and 7. However GetMessagePos() in the WM_CONTEXTMENU handler works perfectly.

Comment: Actually, GetCursorPos works. GetMessagePos really doesn't. If I invoke a dialog using my context menu, then close that dialog, GetMessagePos gives me the position where I clicked to close. GetCursorPos seems to be giving better behavior.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>To display the menu, all you need is the coords passed to you by WM_CONTEXTMENU or WM_RBUTTONUP (These are of course not normal messages, but something generated by the tray and you therefore don't have to deal with mouse vs keyboard)</strike>

Shell_NotifyIconGetRect is used if you want to display a toast (custom window) near the tray. On < 7 you can emulate it with findwindow by looking for the TrayNotifyWnd class with Shell_TrayWnd as the parent

Comment: This doesn't work. Those messages don't contain coordinates in LPARAM.

Comment: David's right about this. These are callback messages, not normal windows messages.  lParam contains the message.