# Delphi XE prevent opening popup with trayicon right click

Tags: delphi

I've added a TrayIcon to my form and I've assigned a PopupMenu to it. (Delphi XE4).
I've added the event for left-click on TrayIcon's MouseUp event, so the popup is displayed when user left-clicks it. The code below:

```
procedure TForm1.TrayIcon1MouseUp(Sender: TObject;
    Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft then PopupMenu1.Popup(Screen.Width, Screen.Height-TaskBarHeight-5);
  if Button = TMouseButton.mbRight then
    begin
      //do nothing
    end;
end;
```

The PopupMenu is displayed above the taskbar, on the right side of the screen.

I want the PopupMenu to be displayed ONLY when user left-clicks the TrayIcon and to stay hidden when the user right-clicks the TrayIcon, but I didn't figure it out yet how to do it.

Any help on this, please?

Comment: Disassociate the popup menu with the TrayIcon.

Comment: Don't assign the Popup menu to the TrayIcon. You're displaying it from your code.

Comment: Thanks Ken & Sertac for answering. That was the problem, I assigned the PopupMenu to TrayIcon. I've removed the assignment and all is fine now. After that I've come here and saw your right answers. But I don't know how to mark your comments as 5 stars...

Answer (score 1):

You've attached the menu to the `PopupMenu` property. That means it is shown when the user right-clicks. Which is not what you want. You'll need to set `PopupMenu` to `nil`.

On top of that, the `OnClick` event is what you should handle. That is, semantically, the event that corresponds to a left-click. For a normal control, there are ways other than the mouse to click a control. It can be done with the keyboard for instance. The VCL translates these low-level input events into the `OnClick` event.

As it happens, notification icons are special. The underlying system component handles keyboard input by way of the system faking mouse events. I think that is a historical accident to ensure compatibility with notification icon handlers that existed before the shell supported keyboard access of the notification area. So, as it happens, handling the `OnMouseUp` event will also respond to keyboard input. However, I still feel that would be semantically wrong. Use `OnClick`.

Your code will place the popup menu in a completely bogus location in many scenarios. For instance multi-monitor setups. When the taskbar is on the left monitor, your code shows the menu on the right hand monitor. When the taskbar is at the top of the screen, your code shows the menu at the bottom.

When `TTrayIcon` shows the popup menu, it uses `GetCursorPos`. That is an error by the VCL designer. That returns the instantaneous position of the cursor. So the menu is shown at the position of the cursor when the input event is handled, rather than the position when the input event was generated. So, if the cursor moves in between the system generating the input event, and the control handling, the menu will be positioned incorrectly. In fact the VCL makes this error repeatedly by calling `GetCursorPos` in input event handling code.

Here's an example from my own program, when converted to using `GetCursorPos` to work out where to show the popup menu:

[image]

The popup menu that you can see here is attached to a notification icon. The reason that it is displayed in the wrong place is that the app was briefly busy in the main thread, which I know is a bad thing to do. But it's possible for a machine to be so busy that certain threads do get starved. And this is the consequence of positioning a popup menu with `GetCursorPos`.

Instead of calling `GetCursorPos` as does the VCL code, you can recover the cursor position when the message was generated with a call to `GetMessagePos`. *Although, read on for reasons why using `GetMessagePos` is probably poor advice.*

---

You should do the following:

- Stop handling `OnMouseUp`. Remove that event handler.
- Set the `PopupMenu` property to nil.
- Add an `OnClick` handler and use that to show the menu.

It looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.TrayIcon1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pos: TSmallPoint;
begin
  Pos := TSmallPoint(GetMessagePos()); // position when input message generated

  // see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135788
  SetForegroundWindow(Application.Handle);
  PopupMenu1.Popup(Pos.x, Pos.y);
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
end;
```

Note that the calls to `SetForegroundWindow`, and `PostMessage` are [the well-known trick](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135788) to make it possible for clicks away from the context menu to close the context menu.

---

**Update:** Sertac points out (deep in the comments) that `GetMessagePos` has its own problems. So you could do what the VCL does and call `GetCursorPos`. Or you could switch to `OnMouseUp` (!!) and use the `X` and `Y` coordinates that are passed by the component. Bah humbug! Notification icons are a mess. And I've not done my best ever work in this answer. Ho hum.

Another interesting and related question is here: [How do I position a notification (tray) icon context menu on Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5597525)